# Java recursive method for summing the powers of 2, from 0 to N

Tags: java, methods, recursion

so im trying to learn recursion (i know in this case recursion is not necessary)

i have already written this method, which works

```
public static int method(int number) {
    if(number == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return (int)Math.pow(2,number) + method(number-1);
    }
}
```

this works perfectly for summing the powers of 2 from 0 to number, but i was wondering if there was a way to replace the `Math.pow()` with another recursive method call

Comment: Burn Math.pow() needs only single execution. why do you want to recursion here?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar - _"To iterate is human; to recurse is divine."_

Comment: Why not return the result without loop or recursion? `return (int)Math.pow(2,number+1) -1;`

Comment: @MrSmith42 that would only work for summing the powers of 2, if it was changed to 3 it wouldnt work anymore.  Also this was about learning recursion not the simplest way to sum the powers of 2

Comment: when changed to 3 you can change the formula to `return (int)(Math.pow(3,number+1) -1) / 2`. This can be generalized (with little thought) for any number.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this as a recursive power function:

```
public static int powerOf2(int number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * powerOf2(number - 1);
    }
}
```

Or, as a one-line body:

```
return number > 0 ? 2 * powerOf2(number - 1) : 1;
```

Comment: is there a way to combine both into one method?

Comment: @KailuaBum - The recursive relationship is f(n) = 2^n + f(n-1). You'd need to transform that into a doubly-recursive relationship to get rid of the `2^n` term. Nothing obvious comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

You should define another recursive method to calculate Math.pow(2,n) recursively probably.
However I would suggest to do bit shift operation of 2  to calculate Math.pow(2,n) quickly. For example shifting 2 << (n-1) will do hob here.

Comment: That should be either `2 << (n-1)` or (better) `1 << n`, since 2^1 = 2, not 4.

Comment: It really should be `1 << n`. Using `2 << (n-1)` won't work for `n==0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn Recursion take a well known example of Fabonacci series.

```
public int getNthFibonacci( int n )
    {
        if ( n == 1 || n == 2 ) 
            return 1;

      else
        return getNthFibonacci( n-1 ) + getNthFibonacci( n-2 );
    }

public static void main(String[] args){

        Recursion myRecursor = new Recursion();
        System.out.println( myRecursor.getNthFibonacci(5) );

    }
```

But in your case it can be done by for loop also easily.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       int sum = 0;     
        for (int number = 20; number>0; number--)
        {
            sum += Math.pow(2,number);
        }

        System.out.println(sum);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution:

```
public static int pow (int base, int ex) {
    if (ex == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (ex == 1) {
        return base;
    } else if(ex > 1) {
        return (pow(base, ex - 1) * base);
    } else {
        return pow(base, ex + 1) / base;
    }
}
```

This handle all possible cases where the passed values are integers..

Comment: It would be better to declare `ex` to be an `int`. Otherwise, if it happens to not be an integer value, this method will recurse until the stack overflows.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll edit my answer to work only for integers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little far from strict question your problem is to calculate sum of **geometric series**  which *is a series with a constant ratio between successive terms*.

Your first element is equal to 1 (as 2 pow 0) and your ratio is equal to 2. So instead of using any recursion you can use it with common, well-know, equatation:

```
public long computGemetricSeries(int n) {
  long firstElem = 1;
  long ratio = 2;

  return (firstElem * (1 - Math.pow(ration,n)) / (1 - ratio));
}
```

Or for general term (not only power o 2):

```
public long computGeometricSeries(int n, double ration, double firstElem) {
   return (firstElem * (1 - Math.pow(ration,n)) / (1 - ration));
}
```

If you realy want recursion here you can change `Math.pow(ration,n)` to some recursion function proposed by other answers.

I think it won't help much as resolution to your question but will be a nice good-to-know answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ComputePowerUsingRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(computePower(2,5));  // Passing 2 for power of 2
        System.out.println(computePower(2,-5)); // Number would be +ve or -ve
    }

    /**
     * <p>Compute power</p>
     * 
     *  p(x,n)  =  1              if(x=0)
     *          =  x*p(x,n-1)     if(n>0)
     *          =  (1/x)*p(x,n+1) if(n<0)  
     * @param x
     * @param n
     * @return
     */
    public static double computePower(double x, double n){
        //base case
        if(n==0){
            return 1;
        }else if(n>0){   //recursive condition for postive power
            return x*computePower(x, n-1);
        }else if(n<0){  //recursive condition for negative power
            return (1/x)*computePower(x, n+1);
        }else{ 
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Integer output = 0;
    output = sumOfThePower(end, 1, 1); //input the number you like at 'end' to get the sum
    System.out.println(output);
}
public static Integer sumOfThePower (int end, int start, int mul){
if (start <= end){
    mul =2 * mul;
    return mul + sumOfThePower(end, start + 1, mul);
}
else{
    return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: This does answer the question but It's always better to provide instructions on why and how this piece of code answers the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

My assumption from this question is that you want to add for example,

```
2 + 4 + 8 = 14 by calling func(3)
2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 30 by calling func(4)
```

If so, you can try,

```
public static int SumPowerOf2(int number) {
if (number == 1) {
    return 2;
} else {
    return 2 + (2 * powerOf2(number - 1));
}
```

Going through each stack's frame, we should have below analysis for SumPowerOf2(3)

```
SumPowerOf2(3) => 2 + (2 * SumPowerOf2(2)) = 2 + 2(6) => 2 + 12 => 14
SumPowerOf2(2) => 2 + (2 * SumPowerOf2(1)) => 2 + 2(2) => 2 + 4 => 6
SumPowerOf2(1) => 2
```